# Is putting an "else" in this case relevant or not, and why?

Tags: python, if-statement

I've always had the habit to put else statements but I'm wondering if there's any reason not to, if it works.

Here's an example:

```
def multiply_by_two(number, display_original_number=False):

    result = number*2

    if display_original_number is True:
        return f'Multiplying {number}: {result}'

    return f'{result}'

print(multiply_by_two(5, True))
print(multiply_by_two(5))
```

Output:

```
Multiplying 5: 10
10
```

If I put else: return f'{result}', it's bascially the same thing, right? Is there any reason I would want to put an else statement in such cases?

Comment: yes it's the same effect. Using `else` is a matter of taste.

Comment: if you just want to see the result in terminal they have no effect, but if you want to reuse the result it is matter

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[It is more efficient to use if-return-return or if-else-return?](/q/9191388/90527)", "[What is the difference between "else: return True" and just "return True?"](/q/44608516/90527)"

Comment: See also: "[if else return practice](/q/14847703/90527)"

Answer (score 0):

Within this use case there is no difference functionally. Personal preference would dictate this decision if you find it easier to read back your code using else: .